# SNMP: How to find a computers IP and MAC-address? (Debian)

Tags: linux, debian, ip, snmp

I'm playing around with Net-SNMP and I'm trying to find my computers IP and MAC-address but it's not working. This is the command I'm running:

`snmpget -v 2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.4`

I'm getting this message:

```
IP-MIB::ip = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

I also tried this:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost sysORID.7
```

But all I get back is this:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.7 = OID: IP-MIB::ip
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What does your snmpd config look like?

Answer (score 1):

1. To get interface-related info, you need IF-MIB. Specifically, poll `IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress` OID to get MAC addresses, for example:

   ```
   snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress
   ```

   That should return one or a bunch of lines, depending on how many interfaces are present on the box. They may look something like this:

   ```
   IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress.1 = STRING: 01:23:45:67:89:AA
   IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress.2 = STRING: 01:23:45:67:89:AB
   IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress.3 = STRING: 01:23:45:67:89:AC
   ```

   The `.X` at the end of `IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress.1` indicates the object's index; in this particular case the index of an interface. You can then poll the `IF-MIB::ifDescr` to see which index corresponds to which interface, for example:

   ```
    IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = STRING: sit0
    IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = STRING: eth0
    IF-MIB::ifDescr.3 = STRING: eth1
   ```

   Or, you can walk the entire sub-tree:

   ```
    snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost IF-MIB::ifEntry
   ```

   Since that will produce really long, not particularly readable output, especially if there are a lot of interfaces), you can do something like this to get info about a single interface (with index `2` in this example):

   ```
    snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost IF-MIB::ifEntry | grep '\.2 '
   ```

   Or, you can poll a table and get a neater output (use `-Cf` flag to set delimiter):

   ```
    snmptable -Cf \; -v 2c -c public localhost IF-MIB::ifTable
   ```
2. To get IP addresses you need IP-MIB. You can use the same techniques described above on these OIDs: `IP-MIB::ipAddrTable` and `IP-MIB::ipAddrEntry`.
3. You can explore the MIBs with `snmptranslate` to read descriptions of OIDs, or to see the structure of a MIB. Consult snmptranslate's manpages for more info. For example:

   ```
    snmptranslate -Td IF-MIB::ifTable
    snmptranslate -Tp IP-MIB::ipAddrTable
   ```

Comment: That does not gives any IP address.